# IE Error "Please choose to register or to checkout as guest"

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

As the title says I'm only getting this error in IE. Anyway to fix this? I removed the instance from the .js and the popup disappears but does not allow checkout. Below is the code

```
        //Clear other steps if already populated through javascript
        for (var i = stepIndex; i < this.steps.length; i++) {
            var nextStep = this.steps[i];
            var progressDiv = nextStep + '-progress-opcheckout';
            if ($(progressDiv)) {
                //Remove the link
                $(progressDiv).select('.changelink').each(function (item) {
                    item.remove();
                });
                $(progressDiv).select('dt').each(function (item) {
                    item.removeClassName('complete');
                });
                //Remove the content
                $(progressDiv).select('dd.complete').each(function (item) {
                    item.remove();
                });
            }
        }
    },

    changeSection: function (section) {
        var changeStep = section.replace('opc-', '');
        this.gotoSection(changeStep, false);
    },

    setMethod: function(){
        if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
            this.method = 'guest';
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveMethodUrl,
                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
            );
            Element.hide('register-customer-password');
            this.gotoSection('billing', true);
        }
        else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
            this.method = 'register';
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveMethodUrl,
                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
            );
            Element.show('register-customer-password');
            this.gotoSection('billing', true);
        }
        else{
            alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest').stripTags());
            return false;
        }
        document.body.fire('login:setMethod', {method : this.method});
    },

    setBilling: function() {
        if (($('billing:use_for_shipping_yes')) && ($('billing:use_for_shipping_yes').checked)) {
            shipping.syncWithBilling();
            $('opc-shipping').addClassName('allow');
            this.gotoSection('shipping_method', true);
        } else if (($('billing:use_for_shipping_no')) && ($('billing:use_for_shipping_no').checked)) {
            $('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;
            this.gotoSection('shipping', true);
        } else {
            $('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;
            this.gotoSection('shipping', true);
        }

        // this refreshes the checkout progress column

//        if ($('billing:use_for_shipping') && $('billing:use_for_shipping').checked){
//            shipping.syncWithBilling();
//            //this.setShipping();
//            //shipping.save();
//            $('opc-shipping').addClassName('allow');
//            this.gotoSection('shipping_method');
//        } else {
//            $('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;
//            this.gotoSection('shipping');
//        }
//        this.reloadProgressBlock();
//        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },

    setShipping: function() {
        //this.nextStep();
        this.gotoSection('shipping_method', true);
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },

    setShippingMethod: function() {
        //this.nextStep();
        this.gotoSection('payment', true);
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },

    setPayment: function() {
        //this.nextStep();
        this.gotoSection('review', true);
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },

    setReview: function() {
        this.reloadProgressBlock();
        //this.nextStep();
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

On opcheckout.js line 166 change (please, copy the file and paste on your pacakge/theme:

```
setMethod: function(){
    if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
```

for:

```
setMethod: function(type){
    if (!type) { type = 'login'; }
    var self = jQuery(this);
    if (($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) || type == 'guest') {
```

And, on login.phtml (copy and paste on same folder on your theme), you only need change the onclick event to add the param "guest":

File: /app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

```
onclick="checkout.setMethod('guest');"
```